# Symmetric pairs in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a large data frame that looks like this:

```
> my_table
   track_fid start_gid end_gid
1          1       100      82
2          2        82     100
3          3       100      82
4          4       100      32
5          5        82     100
6          6        82     100
7          7        82     100
8          8       100      82
9          9        34     100
10        10        31     100
```

My aim is to add column `to_from` at the end and populate it with characters `y` or `n`.

Let's take the first row as an example - the value in `start_gid` = 100 and the value in `end_gid` = 82. If another other row in exists anywhere in the table where the values are the inverse, i.e., where `end_gid` = 100  and the value in `start_gid` = 82, I'd like to fill the column `to_from` of both rows with `y`. If the inverse does not exist, the first row should be filled with with n. The key here is to loop over every row and search for it's inverse in the table according to the order of `track_fid`. If an inverse is found where `track_fid` is greater, a y should be inserted.  Once an inverse receives a value the `y`, it cannot be used again.

For example, this would be a sample output:

```
> output
   track_fid start_gid end_gid to_from
1          1       100      82       y
2          2        82     100       y
3          3       100      82       y
4          4       100      32       n
5          5        82     100       y
6          6        82     100       y
7          7        82     100       n
8          8       100      82       y
9          9        34     100       n
10        10        31     100       n
```

Is there a way to create such an output in R ?

Something along the lines of:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(my_table)) {
if(my_table[i-1,"start_gid"]= my_table[i,"end_gid"]) {
my_table$to_from = "y" } else { my_table$to_from = "n"}


> str(output)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ track_fid: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ start_gid: int  100 82 100 100 82 82 82 100 34 31
 $ end_gid  : int  82 100 82 32 100 100 100 82 100 100
 $ to_from  : Factor w/ 2 levels "n","y": 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1
```

Comment: creating `sum`, `prod` and then `group_by()` helps in taking a step further

Comment: The offered "correct answer appears flawed. There are an even number of (82,100) pairs. Please correct the example or refine the question.

Comment: @42- No, the example is fine. Row 7 doesn't have a match.

Comment: exactly, the output is correct.  The order of operations is the problem - by ascending `track_fid` is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this without a loop in R. You can do this with `for` loops and `next` and `break` statements. But in such a case I turn to Rcpp if the problem size is large.

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp(code = "
          #include <Rcpp.h>
          // [[Rcpp::export]]
          Rcpp::LogicalVector myfun(const Rcpp::IntegerVector x, const Rcpp::IntegerVector y) {
            Rcpp::LogicalVector res(x.length());
            for (int i=0; i<(x.length()-1); i++) {
              if(res(i)) continue;
              for (int j=i+1; j<x.length(); j++) {
                if (res(j)) continue;
                if (x(i) == y(j) && x(j) == y(i)) {
                   res(i) = true;
                   res(j) = true;
                   break;
                }
              }
            }
            return res;
          }
          ")

DF$from_to <- myfun(DF$start_gid, DF$end_gid)
#   track_fid start_gid end_gid from_to
#1          1       100      82    TRUE
#2          2        82     100    TRUE
#3          3       100      82    TRUE
#4          4       100      32   FALSE
#5          5        82     100    TRUE
#6          6        82     100    TRUE
#7          7        82     100   FALSE
#8          8       100      82    TRUE
#9          9        34     100   FALSE
#10        10        31     100   FALSE
```

Comment: I believe I found a [solution without loops](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41396144/3817004)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the detailed description of the algorithm, we can also construct a different solution using `data.table` without loops.

First, we count the unique combinations of `start_gid` and `end_gid`:

```
pairs <- dt[, .N, by = .(start_gid, end_gid)]
pairs

#   start_gid end_gid N
#1:       100      82 3
#2:        82     100 4
#3:       100      32 1
#4:        34     100 1
#5:        31     100 1
```

It's obvious that the first 3 occurrences of (100, 82) and (82, 100) will have an inverse partner while the 4th occurence of (82, 100) has not. Also, the occurrences of (100, 32), (34, 100), and (31, 100) have no inverse partners.

We now determine the maximum number of possible pairings `nmatch` in each group. All occurrences of (100, 82) and (82, 100) belong to the same group *82_100*. If the group consists of only one member, there is no other pairing partner, so `nmatch` is 0.

```
pairs <- pairs[, .(start_gid, end_gid, nmatch = if (.N <= 1L) 0L else min(N)), 
      by = .(grp = paste(pmin(start_gid, end_gid), pmax(start_gid, end_gid), sep = "_"))]
pairs

#      grp start_gid end_gid nmatch
#1: 82_100       100      82      3
#2: 82_100        82     100      3
#3: 32_100       100      32      0
#4: 34_100        34     100      0
#5: 31_100        31     100      0
```

We now join both tables. It is a right join so that all rows of `dt` do appear in the output:

```
out <- pairs[dt, on = .(start_gid, end_gid)]
out
#       grp start_gid end_gid nmatch track_fid
# 1: 82_100       100      82      3         1
# 2: 82_100        82     100      3         2
# 3: 82_100       100      82      3         3
# 4: 32_100       100      32      0         4
# 5: 82_100        82     100      3         5
# 6: 82_100        82     100      3         6
# 7: 82_100        82     100      3         7
# 8: 82_100       100      82      3         8
# 9: 34_100        34     100      0         9
#10: 31_100        31     100      0        10
```

In the final step, the first `nmatch` pairings in each group are marked, and the result is ordered by `track_fid`

```
out <- out[, .(track_fid, to_from = seq_len(.N) <= nmatch), by = .(start_gid, end_gid)]
out[order(track_fid)]
     start_gid end_gid track_fid to_from
# 1:       100      82         1    TRUE
# 2:        82     100         2    TRUE
# 3:       100      82         3    TRUE
# 4:       100      32         4   FALSE
# 5:        82     100         5    TRUE
# 6:        82     100         6    TRUE
# 7:        82     100         7   FALSE
# 8:       100      82         8    TRUE
# 9:        34     100         9   FALSE
#10:        31     100        10   FALSE
```

### Benchmark 1: Original data (10 rows)

Comparison of the `data.table` solution with Rolands's `Rcpp` solution using the original data set with only 10 rows:

#### Code

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  dt = {
    dt[, .N, by = .(start_gid, end_gid)][
      , .(start_gid, end_gid, nmatch = if (.N <= 1L) 0L else min(N)), 
      by = .(grp = paste(pmin(start_gid, end_gid), pmax(start_gid, end_gid), sep = "_"))][
        dt, on = .(start_gid, end_gid)][
          , .(track_fid, to_from = seq_len(.N) <= nmatch), 
          by = .(start_gid, end_gid)][
            order(track_fid)]
  },
  rcpp_source = {
    sourceCpp(code = "
          #include <Rcpp.h>
          // [[Rcpp::export]]
          Rcpp::LogicalVector myfun(const Rcpp::IntegerVector x, const Rcpp::IntegerVector y) {
            Rcpp::LogicalVector res(x.length());
            for (int i=0; i<(x.length()-1); i++) {
              if(res(i)) continue;
              for (int j=i+1; j<x.length(); j++) {
                if (res(j)) continue;
                if (x(i) == y(j) && x(j) == y(i)) {
                   res(i) = true;
                   res(j) = true;
                   break;
                }
              }
            }
            return res;
          }
          ")
    dt$from_to <- myfun(dt$start_gid, dt$end_gid)
    dt
  },
  rcpp_func = {
    dt$from_to <- myfun(dt$start_gid, dt$end_gid)
    dt
  }
)
```

#### Results

```
Unit: microseconds
        expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq       max neval
          dt 2873.017 3233.418 3466.5484 3408.0495 3558.705  6345.633   100
 rcpp_source 8112.335 8537.114 8932.8953 8811.2385 9173.150 12093.931   100
   rcpp_func  101.192  121.582  142.0769  137.4405  154.620   255.246   100
```

As expected, the Rcpp function alone is more than 20 times faster than the `data.table` solution (for the given toy size sample data). However, if the call to `sourceCPP` is included it needs more than twice the time of the `data.table` solution.

Note, that the `data.table`code has been compacted by *chaining* `data.table` queries.

### Benchmark 2: Larger data sets

As suggested by @Roland, I've compared the `data.table` solution with the `Rcpp` on larger data sets:
[image]

For data frames with less than 1000 rows, `Rcpp` is faster than the `data.table` solution. For larger data frames, the `data.table` solution scales much better than the `Rcpp` solution. Note, this is a characteristic of the implemented algorithm and must *not* be attributed to `Rcpp` in general.

Comment: I'd also order `out` before the final step. I also believe this will be quite a bit slower than the Rcpp solution.

Comment: @Roland I do believe as well the Rcpp solution is faster. The `data.table` solution requires 4 calls, 3 with grouping, one join. (I guess there are some `data.table` gurus around who know how to do this better than me). Anyway, it was an interesting exercise to find a different approach.

Comment: The time consuming parts are probably not so much the data.table operations but the calls to `pmin`/`pmax` and `paste` and the vector scans (`<=`) in the last step. Maybe a rolling join could be used there? Still, it's much faster than an R loop. Nice approach.

Comment: Did you benchmark with OP's example? Because that's way too small.

Comment: @Roland Benchmark on larger data sets added as suggested by you.